# Having trouble when publishing android app to google play store. "Fully Shadowed APK"

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I received this message

> Fully shadowed APK
>   PROBLEM
>   This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes.
>   RESOLUTION
>   Remove this APK from your release or review the targeting and version codes of the APKs that you are including in this release.

If i deactivate the previous apk, will it stop other user from using that version they have installed.

I want to be safe. Don't want user fail to use the current application because I deactivate it.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, that you increased the version code in the new APK?

Comment: The one with version code 6 is the one having exclamation mark, after i clicked Review button

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating a version means, that new users won't be able to download it anymore. Keeping it might be useful if the new version has limited compatibility. In this case, users with incompatible devices will be able to download an older compatible version.

Comment: Thanks but the older apk is the production version. If I deactivate it in the alpha or beta tracks, will it remove the production version ? See the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652630/google-play-console-does-deactivation-of-production-code-version-in-alpha-or-be

Comment: @Regis_AG I'm not sure, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating won't stop existing users using the app. The only thing it prevents is new users installing that version from the Play store, which sounds like is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks but the older apk is the production version. If I deactivate it in the alpha or beta tracks, will it remove the production version ? See the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652630/google-play-console-does-deactivation-of-production-code-version-in-alpha-or-be